# events are not triggerring after added by append method in jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

```
     <div class="sortable-sections">
            <fieldset class="section draggable" id="flSectionType">
                <div class="btn-drag section-handle hidden-view">
                </div>
                <div class="section-header">
                    <span class="section-label">Job Requirements</span> <a class="section-info" href="#more-info"
                        title="Minimum Education, Minimum Work Experience, Required Licenses/Certifications, Required Skills, Knowledge, and Abilities needed to perform the job.">
                        ?</a>
                </div>
                <div class="sortable-items">
                </div>
                <a class="section-add-item hidden-view" id="addJR" href="#add-item" data-item='{"id":"addJR","template":"requirement","item_type":"Job Requirement"}'>
                    Add a new Job Requirement</a>
            </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="section draggable">
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="section draggable">
       </fieldset>
     <div>
```

The above code will generate a list of sections which can be dragged with in the sortable-sectons.

I am using the following script to remove sections manually and adding it back to sortable-sections, but it is not registering the jquery events.

```
 var $section = $('.sortable-sections').find($('#flSectionType');
 $('.sortable-sections').find($('#flSectionType').remove();
 ......
 .......
 $('.sortable-sections').append($section.val());
```

After appending the section, the event which are registered for the section-add-item css classes are not triggering.
Note:
 instead of "**on**" used the "**live**" method. but it is not holding all attributes.

**Edit**:
Event code:

```
   $('.section-add-item').on('click', function (e) {
        that.addSection(this);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

instead of drag and drop, manually i am ordering the section on initial load.

Comment: Where's the code for the event being wired up? Or are you using a jQueryUI function like sortable/draggable?

Comment: If you are not using JQuery 1.3, do not use .live() as it's deprecated. For 1.7, use .on(), otherwise use .delegate().

Comment: Not a single line of event related code here, so can't give a definitive answer. If that's all the code you are using, then it's just that - you have zero events going on here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.section-add-item` must already exist when adding the event and the usage of `on` is wrong

```
$('body').on('click', '.section-add-item', function (e) {

});
```

instead of the body you can add another parent of `.section-add-item` that already exists before `.section-add-item` is created.

Comment: I fixed this issue by using detach instead of remove method.